# removing decimals in crystal reports for number field

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field year which is string type coming from db side.So I converted that to number and adding 1 more year to that to show like this:

```
 Year:2014-2015
```

Below is the formula.

```
'Year' & ':' & tonumber({FocusOnCustomer.YEAR})&'-'&(tonumber({FocusOnCustomer.YEAR})+1)
```

Everything is working fine in designer.But when I view the report in cr viewer I am getting data like this.

```
2,014.00-2,015.00
```

I want to remove decimals and comas

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
ToText( ToNumber({FocusOnCustomer.YEAR}), "#")
```

Comment: Hi Craig with this code I am getting only 2014.But I need to get 2014-2015.Please help

Comment: @user2846028 If craig's code gives you the string '2014' then what, logically, do you need to concatenate to make the string 'Year:2014-2015'? It's a very small jump from one to the other.

Answer (score 5):

Right-click on the field or formula
Select Format Field
On the Number tab, choose the format to use from the list or click Customize to create a custom format.
Click OK

[image]

[Website Link](https://www.kb.blackbaud.com/articles/Article/91354)

Answer (score 0):

ToText parameters:

ToText(x, y, z, w)

x = The number to convert to text
y = The number of decimal places to include in result (optional). The value will be rounded to that decimal place.
z = The character to use as the thousands separator. If you don’t specify one, it will use your application default. (Optional.)
w = The character to use as the decimal separator. If you don’t specify one, it will use your application default. (Optional.)