# How to remove decimal in crytal report

Tags: crystal-reports

How to remove decimal from report by using crystal report when export to excel,
i have data in crytal report result = 110,973 when export report with format format excel
i get data resutl =110,973.8333333 if highlight column result, so how to remove decimal .8333333 or how to setting format in crytal report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to removing decimals try this :

[removing decimals in crystal reports for number field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609725/removing-decimals-in-crystal-reports-for-number-field)

Comment: i think better with truncate({tbl.myfield}) or int({tbl.myfield})